# Remove Duplicate in drop down list ASP CLASSIC

Tags: asp-classic

I retrieved all the records from database, and there are lots of duplicates due to pushing all the records into drop down list.

Code:

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM insite.holiday where calendar_Type= '" &sCalendarType& "' order by date_holiday"
```

Reason for not using distinct is due to other fields are required from this query.

Before:

> 2013,2013,2013,2013,..... 2014,2014... 2015,2015,2015...

I want to filter up the record in drop down list to become:

> 2013,2014,2015

I know it need a condition in between the loop but I can't figure it out.

Please Help. thanks

Below is my code :

```
response.write(" <select name=""year1"">")
Do While not rs.eof
    nDateHoliday = rs("date_holiday")
    Ndate= year(nDateHoliday)
    response.write("<option value=" & Ndate & ">" & Ndate & "</option>" & vbCrLf)
    rs.MoveNext()
Loop
response.write("</select>")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx guys for your hardwork, i finally solve my questions thanks again..

Cheers

```
Dim arrDates(), x, blnExists



Dim arrYear


arrYear = rs.GetRows()



Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")



For Each strItem in arrYear

    If Not objDictionary.Exists(strItem) Then
        objDictionary.Add strItem, strItem


    End If

Next

intItems = objDictionary.Count - 1

ReDim arrItems(intItems)

i = 0



For Each strKey in objDictionary.Keys
    arrItems(i) = strKey
    i = i + 1
Next


'display out'
    response.write(" <select name=""year4"">")

For Each strItem in arrItems


   response.write("<option value=" & strItem & ">" & strItem & "</option>" & vbCrLf)
Next

            response.write("</select>")
yearReq4=Request.Form("year4")
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not change your query to return a distinct list of years or is it also returning additional data?

Comment: i neeed it to return additional data due to other functions require of it, or is there a way to run two sql query togather in 1 asp page?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to simply store the distinct values in dynamic array, checking in each iteration that the current item does not exist yet:

```vbs
Dim arrDates(), x, blnExists
ReDim arrDates(-1)
Do While not rs.eof
    nDateHoliday = rs("date_holiday")
    Ndate= year(nDateHoliday)
    blnExists = False
    For x=0 To UBound(arrDates)
        If arrDates(x)=Ndate Then
            blnExists = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If Not(blnExists) Then
        ReDim Preserve arrDates(UBound(arrDates) + 1)
        arrDates(UBound(arrDates)) = Ndate
    Next
    rs.MoveNext()
Loop
rs.Close
response.write(" <select name=""year1"">")
For x=0 To UBound(arrDates)
    response.write("<option value=""" & arrDates(x) & """>" & arrDates(x) & "</option>" & vbCrLf)
Next
response.write("</select>")
Erase arrDates
```

**Note**: if you have lots of records in `rs`, e.g. more than 100 you better use something like Dictionary, which has faster search.

Answer (score 0):

Instead using array for collect years, as suggest Shadow Wizard, you can use string:

```
Dim sYears, iTmp
sYears = ""
Do while not rs.Eof
    iTmp = CStr(Year(rs("date_holiday")))
    If (InStr(sYear, "," & iTmp) = -1) Then
        sYears = sYears & "," & iTmp
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
If (Len(sYears) >= 1) Then
    sYears = Mid(sYears, 2)
End If
Dim arrYears
arrYears = Split(sYears, ",")
' print array
```